What is the rendering method used in "viewport shading: solid" in Blender?
https://streamable.com/km0hv0

I want to make a low-poly game.
I noticed that in blender in viewport shading mode, when the camera rotates, the face progressively change color, from grey to black, depending on the angle between the camera and the normal of the faces.
Usually, when I load my model or level inside an engine like godot, with or without lighting, it's difficult to differentiate faces.
Is it possible to easily recreate this method of displaying faces in an engine? It makes it easy to see 3D shapes and perspective. (the result is similar when wireframe is disabled)
EDIT:
This seems like a partial answer, it sort of does what I want, but I now want to decide what angle have what shade of gray.


This looks like it might just be a Fresnel term, (n • v), though possibly using a shifted view direction. Do you find faces are brightest when facing directly at the camera, or slightly tilted in a particular direction? (I don't have Blender installed on this device to check myself just now)

Generally, I would say yes, although some faces are darker "at first" when facing some directions, so there might be an offset somewhere. By "•" you mean dot product? So that means I must write a vertex shader and a fragment shader.

Yep, standard dot product, possibly scaled and clamped to keep it in a usable range.

actually, I just dot the normal with (1,0,0), use the result to make a vector, and put this in albedo in the visual shader, it seems to be one part of the solution...

Can you describe what kind of interface you want to use to associate a shade of grey with a particular angle?

Well let a and b be the horizontal and vertical angle between the camera orientation and the normal of a face. From 90 to 75 degrees the grey would be rgb 0.2 0.2 0.2, 75..15, the grey would interpolate between rgb 0.2 and rgb 0.8, and 15..0 it would just be rgb 0.8. But it's really better to use blender and see how it behaves. I might need to ask the blender dev team.
